# PHP days left and gone from date

Tags: php, date

I want to get a user registered date, count the days since registration and show max days left to given days and show message after period ends.

What I got so far works:

```
$regDatestr = '2020-04-09 19:38:10';
$regDate = strtotime($regDatestr);
$regSince = time() - $regDate;
$days = round ($regSince / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ));
$maxDays = 20;
$maxDaysstr = strtotime("-$maxDays days");
$maxReg = ($regSince + $maxDaysstr); 
$daysleft =  time() - $maxReg;
$restDays = round ($daysleft / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ));

if ($regdate <= $maxDaysstr) : 
    echo 'period ended'
else : 
    echo 'Registered since' . $days . ' .days . Rest days ' . $restDays . '
endif;
```

$daysleft and days  gives me the right days. But the period doesnt end exact after 20 days.

What I need is max 20 days since registration date. So when

```
'2020-04-09 19:38:10';
```

plus 20 days should end the period at

```
'2020-04-29 19:38:10';
```

but it seems my if condition doesnt work as expected. So Im getting "Registered since 21 days. Rest days 0".

Why is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have an typo in with your variable names

```
if ($regdate <= $maxDaysstr)
```

should be

```
if ($regDate <= $maxDaysstr)
```

and your code could be shorter

```
$regDatestr = '2020-04-01 19:38:10';
$regDate = new DateTime($regDatestr);

$diffToday = $regDate->diff(new DateTime());

$maxDays = 10;
$diffMax = $regDate->diff(new DateTime("-$maxDays days"));

if ($diffMax->invert == 0) :
    echo 'period ended';
else :
    echo 'Registered since ' . $diffToday->days . ' .days . Rest days ' . $diffMax->days;
endif;
```

Comment: Thank you! But I dont get the difference betwenn my "if ($regdate <= $maxDaysstr)" and the one you wrote after "should be". Could you please clarify?

Comment: your variable $regDate has a large D, but you wrote it lower case 
PHP is case sensitive